# How to resolve missing artifact error when using Eclipse AWS plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, plugins, aws-sdk

I am using the [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) Java plugin for Eclipse. I didn't have any issues during the installation process but after I used the plugin to create a sample DynamoDB project, I got this error

`Missing artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cl....watchmetris.jar:1.11.123(click for 156 more...).`

clicking didn't do anything.

I thought the error was due to the fact that I didn't install that jar during the installation process - I only installed "AWS Toolkit for Eclipse".

I went back into Eclipse and installed every non optional plugin from the aws(see below)
[image]

After I restarted Eclipse and tried creating my DynamoDB project again, I get a different failed to read artifact descriptor error(see below)
[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue before or know what the solution is? Elastic load balancer should be apart of AWS Toolkit which I installed. I've tried removing and reinstalling the aws plugin but I'am still getting missing artifact errors. I've looked at other threads on AWS plugin for Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone dealing with this issue with this issue, I got it to work! I can't really explain why it works though - maybe Maven's way of resetting some  setting.

What I did was go inside pom.xml, the configuration file for Maven, and into the Dependencies tab. This is what I saw 
[image]

I reasoned that the missing artifact was in the aws-java-sdk jar so I removed it. I then deleted the project from disk and created a new one. The new project came with the correct dependencies and no compiler errors!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your AWS Toolkit, it's a problem of your Maven. Please try to create a project with Maven to check if Maven's setting is correct. If Maven is correct, please see your pom file in XML and check the dependency is correct? If you cannot create Maven project, it's means that your Maven setting is wrong somewhere!

Comment: I was able to create a new maven project. The pom file came from Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error "*failure to transfer com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk* ...". The pom resolution could work, but here's another solution. So, when you start an aws project for the first time, certain artifacts necessary for maven are stored under .m2\repository\com\amazonaws.

What happened to me was that when I deleted one of my aws projects, I also deleted the resources being referred to which was somewhere in the aforementioned directory. And because the directory existed, eclipse's aws toolkit didn't bother downloading it again. I solved it by just deleting the $home.m2\repository\com\amazonaws directory. So next time I created a new aws project, it had to download all the artifacts.