# Convert to maven project in Eclipse results in an endless loop

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, amazon-web-services

This is related to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566004/how-to-resolve-missing-artifact-error-when-using-eclipse-aws-plugin)

One of the answers suggested that the error wasn't related to the AWS plugin but rather Maven. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation) as a reference to install the Maven plugin. The installation finished fine.

I made a simple Java project called Maven with a single class that outputs "Hello Maven". I then tried to configure the java project into a Maven project by going to configure -> convert to Maven Project. These are my settings for configuring my simple project into a Maven project(all default)
[image]

After clicking finish, I get into an endless loop. I've tried restarting Eclipse but that didn't work. This tells me that the issue in my other question was related to Maven. I'am new to Maven. Can someone guide me into the next step for debugging this issue? There's no error output I can look at.

Comment: I would suggest you use a new version of Eclipse like Mars or Neon. They have Maven included.

Comment: I am using Neon

Comment: Do it by hand.   One way is to create a new maven project from the command line and copy the sources in.

Comment: @committedandroider: So why do you install m2e? If you unpack Eclipse Neon, m2e and Maven is already included.

Comment: @JFMeier Did not know that. Actually didn't really know what Maven was until today